# mail is not coming from my hosting server after migration to gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

My PHP script sending mail to all other mail perfectly, but not getting any mail in trustmedi.com. Ff I send mail from my gmail to dummy@trustmedi.com, it's working. I had already tried gmail smtp, PHPmailer but it's not working. My dummy.trustmedi.com is using gmail server.
from my previous post I have got following answer
The main reason is that your domain is listed on SORBS DUHL black list which says:

> Additional Information: [Dynablock] Dynamic IP address, use your ISPs
>   mail server Listed but has active as exception(s) and therefore might
>   NOT be blocked.
>   166.62.27.124 is an active exception for the network 166.62.24.0/22.
>   166.62.27.151 is an active exception for the network 166.62.24.0/22.